# View that call a function with parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that decrypt a column and return it with some other columns. The parameters of this function are ID and PRIVATE KEY.
The encrypted column have document information and I need to send this information of all my recerds time to time. What I need its a query like this:

```
select person.NAME,person.EMAIL, DECRYPTFUNCTION(person.ID,mypass) from person
WHERE person.BIRTHDAY BETEWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-15'
```

But "mypass" is a parameter to the function. Whats the best way to do this view and get this parameter?

Comment: You need a table-valued function, not a view.

Comment: [Query Language (SQL) Functions/SQL Functions Returning TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)

Comment: Thank you. I did that way and worked fine.